How do you idiomatically DRY up rust code without upsetting the borrow checker?
Context
Coming from OOP I'm finding as I implement various traits and functions on my structs, I want to abstract bits and pieces of them out. But whenever I do, I run into borrow checker issues. I'm looking for some advice on best rust practice. I'm open to completely changing my architecture, as part of my rust journey is to leave the OOP head space.
Problem 1
The first case I keep coming across is abstracting an implementation over all objects of a trait.
Consider this simple trait and an implementation
trait MyContainer<T>
{
    fn iter_mut(&mut self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &mut T>;
    fn check_value(&self, item: &T) -> bool;
}

struct VecContainer<T> {
    items: Vec<T>,
    checker: fn(&T) -> bool,
}

impl<T> MyContainer<T> for VecContainer<T> {
    fn iter_mut(&mut self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &mut T> {
        self.items.iter_mut()
    }
    
    fn check_value(&self, item: &T) -> bool {
        (self.checker)(item)
    }
}

So far so good. But now I have another trait I'd like my containers to implement
trait Checker<T> {
    fn check_all(&mut self) -> bool;
}

impl<T> Checker<T> for VecContainer<T> {
    fn check_all(&mut self) -> bool {
        self.items.iter_mut().all(|item| (self.checker)(item))
    }
}

Still good. But hey I notice that anything that implements MyContainer could also implement Checker... So let's abstract it over all types that implement MyContainer
impl<T, TImpl> Checker<T> for TImpl where TImpl: MyContainer<T> {
    fn check_all(&mut self) -> bool {
        self.iter_mut().all(|item| self.check_value(item))
    }
}

Here the borrow checker gets in the way, since I'm now accessing these fields through trait methods, which require borrowing self. First borrow is in self.iter_mut(), second borrow is in self.check_value(). I understand why it fails, but don't know how to do such an abstraction another way. Ideally I shouldn't have to implement Checker for every single impl of MyContainer. Any recommendations? Or is implementing on each individual implementation the rust way. Is there another way to abstract this logic?
Problem 2
The second problem I keep coming across occurs when trying to abstract methods away into helper functions. For example
// Simple trait for sake of example
trait Mutable {
    fn mutate(&mut self);
    fn compare(&self, other: &Self) -> bool;
}

impl<T> VecContainer<T> where T : Mutable {
    fn complex_check(&mut self, item1: &T, item2: &T) -> bool {
        let mut match1 = None;
        let mut match2 = None;

        for item in self.items.iter_mut() {
            if item.compare(item1) {
                match1 = Some(item);
            }
            else if item.compare(item2) {
                match2 = Some(item);
            }
        }

        if let (Some(match1), Some(match2)) = (match1, match2) {
            match1.mutate();
            match2.mutate();
            true
        }
        else {
            false
        }
    }
}

this is cool and all, but ideally I'd like to abstract that search code behind a helper method, as it cleans up the code and makes it more reusable.
impl<T> VecContainer<T> where T : Mutable {
    fn find_mut(&mut self, item: &T) -> Option<&mut T> {
        self.items.iter_mut().find(|i| i.compare(item))
    }

    fn complex_check(&mut self, item1: &T, item2: &T) -> bool {
        let mut match1 = self.find_mut(item1);
        let mut match2 = self.find_mut(item2);

        if let (Some(match1), Some(match2)) = (match1, match2) {
            match1.mutate();
            match2.mutate();
            true
        }
        else {
            false
        }
    }
}

Uh oh, again the borrow checker now is upset because I'm trying to borrow twice. For a simple example like this, it's not the end of the world. But imagine a more complex situation where I'd like to abstract a helper function. Is this just the rust way? Or is there some better way to architect it so this problem never occurs?

Indeed, what you're doing is very OOP-y and very non Rust-y. Abstraction over external resources is good for testability, abstracting over other things is often overestimated. If you don't have more than two implementations, you don't need a trait.

I've been coming to that conclusion. In my case I'm working on an (yet another) ECS framework. And I want my storage to be swappable between sparse lists and archtype lists. Thus the traits for the not-yet abstracted thing. Also to avoid interior mutability, I have a macro to generate a bunch of different queries for various numbers of type args. Meaning each implementation also needs it's own macro. That's a big onus to put on the implementer. Thus if I could do it over a shared trait it would make things easier. But maybe I'm dreaming too big.

This is simply a limitation of rust (there is probably 1 question with this same core problem posted on SO every 2-3 days). The fundamental issue is that the borrow checker knows that different fields of a struct can be mutably borrowed simultaneously, which essentially is "splitting" the struct. However there is no way to declare that a function borrows only from some subset of a struct arguments fields. There are numerous attempts to address this shortcoming (1 2).

.. as you have noted, this limitation restricts code re-use (DRY) in many cases, because you cannot "move things into a function" in any "obvious way", and in fact, the obvious way - to me and you - is inexpressible in the type system of rust. This has little to do with "OOP way/rust way", etc. Even very 'rustic' code which the most fanatical adherent will approve of suffers from this issue.

Thanks everyone for the input. Because this language is such a challenge to learn, it helps to have these opinions from the community. I always just assume "skill issue". I like what Chayim had to say, as it strikes me that the best way to not have friction with rust, is to minimize your interaction with complex architectures. Thus pre-abstraction should be kept to absolute 0.

A simple solution to the first problem is to give the trait a iter method that returns an iterator over shared references to T. Needing multiple methods for different types of borrowed-ness is common in Rust.

In your second problem the two examples do not perform the same operation, the compiler caught that (your first example wouldn't work if you did the same as the second). In the first example you specifically block having the same value by adding an else block. In the second you don't replicate this so you could hit an issue where the same value is found for both.
Rust usually has no issues pulling out functions except when you access multiple fields (problem 1). You can use strategies from here for that.
